# Reading get response with TIFF file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spark-java

I am developing a web-application where I try to display TIFF file requested from a server. I use [this approach](http://rfvallina.com/blog/2015/08/22/preview-tiff-and-pdf-files-using-html5-file-api/) to display a TIFF file, but I need to get an image from a server via a GET request instead of opening the file from a local computer.

On the server side I am using a Spark-Java framework to send a response. This is the Java code for that purpose:

```
get("tiff", (request, response) -> {
        byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("temp/201600004068.tif"));
        HttpServletResponse raw = response.raw();
        raw.setContentType("image/tiff");
        raw.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
        raw.getOutputStream().flush();
        raw.getOutputStream().close();
        return raw;
    });
```

I can't figure out how to handle the response (input stream in response) in JavaScript to read the file with `FileReader()`.

```
$.get( "/tiff", function( data ) {
  var parentEl = $(this).parent();
  var fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onload = function(e) {
  //Using tiff.min.js library - https://github.com/seikichi/tiff.js/tree/master
  console.debug("Parsing TIFF image...");
  //initialize with 100MB for large files
  Tiff.initialize({
    TOTAL_MEMORY: 100000000
  });
  var tiff = new Tiff({
    buffer: e.target.result
  });
  var tiffCanvas = tiff.toCanvas();
  $(tiffCanvas).css({
    "max-width": "1000000px",
    "width": "100%",
    "height": "auto",
    "display": "block",
    "padding-top": "10px"
  }).addClass("preview");
  $(parentEl).append(tiffCanvas);
}

fr.onloadend = function(e) {
  console.debug("Load End");
}
  fr.readAsArrayBuffer(data);      });
```

When I try to put the response directly into `fr.readAsArrayBuffer(data);` I got an error `Failed to execute 'readAsArrayBuffer' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'`.

When I try to create a Blob based on the response

```
var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'image/tiff'});
  fr.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
```

it's not able to parse TIFF file.

My response looks like this:

[image: Local Host Response]

and I don't understand the meaning of that response.

So how do I retrieve the file from this response?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please post the headers of your response.

Comment: General:   
Request URL:http://localhost:4567/tiff
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:[::1]:4567

Comment: Response Headers:
Content-Type:image/tiff
Server:Jetty(9.0.2.v20130417)
Transfer-Encoding:chunked

Comment: Request Headers:
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:4567
Referer:http://localhost:4567/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Comment: My guess would be the response constent-type being wrong, but it is set to image/tiff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the Sandeep's answer I managed to achieve my question's goal.
It's possible to use XMLHttpRequest() in order to read server's raw response instead of reading from a source folder.

So, request image from javaScript:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

xhr.open('get', "/image?imageName=" + imageName);
xhr.onload = function ( e ) {
    Tiff.initialize({
        TOTAL_MEMORY: 100000000
    });
    var tiff = new Tiff({
        buffer: arrayBuffer
    });

    *//...Any manipulation with tiff file*
};
xhr.send();
```

Handling request on the server side and return raw response:

```
get("/image", (request, response) -> {
    String imageName = request.queryParams("imageName");
    response.raw().setContentType("image/tiff");
    response.raw().setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=image.tiff");
    Path path = Paths.get(IMAGE_DESTINATION + "/" + imageName);
    byte[] data = null;
    try {
        data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    OutputStream out = response.raw().getOutputStream();
    out.write(data);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    return response.raw();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer XMLHttpRequest .Since you are writing bytes you can get the data as arraybuffer in XMLHttpRequest.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', "assets/tif/sample.tif", true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

xhr.onload = function(e) {
    var arrayBuffer = this.response;
    Tiff.initialize({
        TOTAL_MEMORY: 100000000
    });
    var tiff = new Tiff({
        buffer: arrayBuffer
    });
    var dataUrI = tiff.toDataURL();
    console.log(dataUrI);

};
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Thanks! It totally solved my issue, just in another way. In this case, I don't need any manipulation in server side like handling requests and returning responses, HXLHttpRequest() do everything for you. But I still wondering is it possible to read Bytes of the file from response which has been sent from server side and assembling JavaScript File from it?

Comment: you want to create a js file from bytes received from server?

Comment: yes, exactly! That what I was trying to solve, when I read bytes from file in server side (Java) byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("temp/201600004068.tif"));  And send them in response. I've stuck in assembling JavaScript File when a response was caught. How to create "new Tiff" from it?